# A pair of strings as a KEY in reduce function - HADOOP

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hello I am implementing a facebook-like program in java using hadoop framework (I am new to this). The main idea is that I have an input .txt file like this:

---

> Christina Bill,James,Nick,Jessica
>   James Christina,Mary,Toby,Nick
>   ...

The 1st is the user and the comma separated are his friends.

---

In the map function I scan each line of the file and emit the user with each one of his friends like

> Christina Bill
>   Christina James

which will be converted to `(Christina,[Bill,James,..])`...

BUT in the description of my assignment it specifies that the Reduce function will receive as key the tuple of
two users, following by both their friends, you will count the
common ones and if that number is equal or greater than a
set number, like 5, you can safely assume that their
uncommon friends can be suggested. So how exactly do I pass a pair of users to the reduce function. I thought the input of the reduce function has to be the same as the output of the map function. I started coding this but I don't think this is the right approach. Any ideas?

---

```
public class ReduceFunction<KEY> extends Reducer<KEY,Text,KEY,Text> {
private Text suggestedFriend = new Text();

public void reduce(KEY key1,KEY key2, Iterable<Text> value1,Iterable<Text> value2,Context context){
}}
```

Comment: So if i understand well your assignment, you'll have to scan groups of 2 lines to obtains after map and shuffle & sort **(key-couple, [common list], [uncommon list])**

Comment: Not really...It also specifies that I need to scan the file one line at a time and in the map function I need to emit the user with each one of their friends.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the map phase should, indeed, be of the same type as the input of the reduce phase. This means that, if there is a requirement for the input of the reduce phase, you have to change your mapper.

The idea is simple:

```
map(user u,friends F):
for each f in F do
    emit (u-f, F\f)

reduce(userPair u1-u2, friends F1,F2):
#commonFriends = |F1 intersection F2|
```

To implement this logic, you can just use a `Text` key, in which you concatenate the names of the users, using, e.g., the '-' character between them.

Note that in each reduce method, you will only receive two lists of friends, assuming that each user appears once in your input data. Then, you only have to compare the two lists for common names of friends.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that..One question: What does F/f do?

Comment: @K.Moul You are welcome. '\' here denotes set difference. F\{f} (actually) means all the friends F, excluding the friend f that you put in the key. You can alternatively just keep F as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can implement `custom record reader`, read two records at once from input file in `mapper class`. And then emit `context.write(outkey, NullWritable.get());` from mapper class. Now in `reducer class` you need to handle two records came as a key(`outkey`) from mapper class. Good luck !